# Test Imagick Image

Tags: php, centos7, imagick

Hello i'm doing a test with Imagick library with following code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

/* Create a new imagick object */
$im = new Imagick();

/* Create new image. This will be used as fill pattern */
$im->newPseudoImage(50, 50, "gradient:red-black");

/* Create imagickdraw object */
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

/* Start a new pattern called "gradient" */
$draw->pushPattern('gradient', 0, 0, 50, 50);

/* Composite the gradient on the pattern */
$draw->composite(Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0, 50, 50, $im);

/* Close the pattern */
$draw->popPattern();

/* Use the pattern called "gradient" as the fill */
$draw->setFillPatternURL('#gradient');

/* Set font size to 52 */
$draw->setFontSize(52);

/* Annotate some text */
$draw->annotation(20, 50, "Hello World!");

/* Create a new canvas object and a white image */
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage(350, 70, "white");

/* Draw the ImagickDraw on to the canvas */
$canvas->drawImage($draw);

/* 1px black border around the image */
$canvas->borderImage('black', 1, 1);

/* Set the format to PNG */
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image */
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
?>
```

The output of this script should be this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5f30.jpg

However i got the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4466 in /home/andrea/domains/domain.it/public_html/test/magick.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /home/andrea/domains/domain.it/public_html/test/magick.php(38): Imagick->drawImage(Object(ImagickDraw)) #1 {main} thrown in /home/andrea/domains/domain.it/public_html/test/magick.php on line 38
```

PHP Version is PHP Version 7.4.27
Imagick version is https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBjF7.jpg

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the font in addition to font size before calling annotation:

```
/* Set font */
$draw->setFont('DejaVu-Sans');

/* Set font size to 52 */
$draw->setFontSize(52);
```

Note that available fonts are varying across setups, and you will get a "The path does not exist" error if you try to set the font which is not available to the Imagick library. You can figure them out by dumping `Imagick::queryFonts()` results, or by executing `convert -list font` command if you have ImageMagick tools installed.